# converting partition on the SD card to FAT

Tags: linux, sd-card

I created partitions on the SD card with:

> sudo mkfs -t vfat -n ZED_BOOT /dev/sdb1
>   sudo mkfs -t ext4 -L ROOT_FS /dev/sdb2

The consule shows the commands went through ok, but when I report the partitions:

> sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
>     p

It tells me the partitions are of type Linux rather than FAT and EXT4.
How can I convert the partitions to FAT and EXT4?

[image: a busy cat]
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

File system types and partition types are two different things.  Partition types are eventually just a hint to the operating system.  This hint is usually ignored by Linux as it just has a look into the actual contents of the partitions to derive the file system: Mounting `/dev/sdb1` would happily succeed and the output of `mount` would tell you that it is mounted as `vfat`.

Tables turn when you try to open the FAT partition on a Windows box, as Windows actually honors the partition type.

To properly adjust the partition table to the actual file systems, use `fdisk` again:

```
# fdisk /dev/sdb1
[…]
Command (m for help): t
Partition number (1,2, default 2): 1
Partition type (type L to list all types): b

Changed type of partition 'Linux' to 'W95 FAT32'.

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Syncing disks.
```

That's all.  As your first partition's label suggests, you are trying to set-up a ZedBoard.  I think you actually won't have to bother with partition types in this case, it just works like a charm. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the partition table with `fdisk` or `gparted` or something like that. The partition is probably formatted correctly; it's just mislabeled in the table.